# Using CQL syntax query with DataFrame in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

We're trying to use PySpark with Cassandra connector to migrate Cassandra data between clusters.
We need to be able to use CQL specific syntax in our queries, to limit the data we migrate. Having full partition key (consisting of two fields) is still selecting too much data, so we need more restrictive filtering condition.
Selection criteria works ok when done with CQLSH tool, where we can use CQL statement like:
select * from ns.table where pk1 = 'val1' and pk2 = 'val2' and timestamp > maxTimeuuid("abc") and timestamp < minTimeuuid("xyz")
// pk1, pk2 - partition key fields, timestamp - next field in primary key

but the problem is that minTimeuuid() and maxTimeuuid() are CQL - specific functions, and seems that PySpark DataFrame does not allow filtering based on Cassandra specific functions. Only when it resembles regular SQL syntax ( field = value kind of comparisons ) does it work.

Tried filtering DataFrame with .filter() condition, or SparkContext sql() function - either one gives errors about unknown functions ( minTimeuuid() or maxTimeuuid() ).
Similarly tried using token('..') function, and 'token()' function is flagged by Spark as unknown function as well.

Are there any examples how CQL specific functions can be used as filtering conditions with PySpark/DataFrame ( or maybe RDD if not with DataFrame)?